# Whats the difference between the following object Instantiation in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

If I create a class in VB called Test,  I noticed I can instantiate it like:

```
Dim test As New Test
```

or

```
Dim test As New Test()
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no difference, they are the same, VB.NET will ignore the () since no parameters are being passed in.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one. Both versions will call the parameter-less constructor of the Test class. The second one just has parentheses.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct. But I nitpickishly disagree with saying that VB.NET *"generally"* doesn't care about parentheses. That's not really true; most of the time it does care. It just doesn't care about them for calling a parameter-less constructor.

Comment: Removed that part of my answer. I said generally because you can remove the parentheses on any parameter-less method call without any problems. In the case of method calls that have parameters though, you're right, the compiler most certainly cares. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Actually, you can remove the parentheses on any call to a parameter-less constructor, *or* any call to a parameter-less property. Properties are treated this way because the VB team wanted them to take on a syntax more like a field, since that's how they're most often called. You *do* need the parentheses to call a method, even if it doesn't take any parameters. The IDE will automatically add them if you omit them from a line, however.